# Let $E$ be a vector space with countable basis.Construct a linear isomorphism between $E$ and $E \oplus E.$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations, direct-sum

In the [book](http://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4%E2%80%A6) of *linear algebra* by Werner Greub, at page $63$, it is asked that

> Let $E$ be a vector space with countable basis.Construct a linear
>   isomorphism between $E$ and $E \oplus E.$

I first thought that the direct sum is an internal sum, and defined a map $\phi: E \to E \oplus E$ by 
$$x_v \to x_v + x_v,$$
where $\{x_v\}$ is a basis for $E$, and I argued that for any $u,v$ the vectors $x_v + x_v$ and $x_u + x_u$ are linearly independent.Moreover, since this set is a maximal linearly independent set, it is a basis for $E$.

So my questions are;

-Is my proof correct ?

-why do we need $E$ to have a countable basis ? Is it because, as I do, we need to be able to give indices to each member of the basis ? I mean if the basis wasn't countable, we couldn't give them indices, right ?

-Is there any alternative mapping than that satisfying the same conditions ?

Comment: All your elements map into the linear space $\{(x,y) \in E \oplus E: x=y\} \neq E$ so $\phi$ is not onto.

Comment: You couldn't give the basis indices from $\mathbb{N}$ if it were not countable, but indices from $\mathbb{R}$ are also allowed, e.g., or from any set, for that matter.

Comment: An internal sum only makes sense when $U,V \subseteq X$ for some vector space $X$ and linear subspaces $U,V$ of it, with $ U \cap V = \{0\}$. So we have an extermal sum (is finite product) here.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma So just be clear, it the basis weren't countable, we could give them indices from any uncountable set ?

Comment: yes, if you know set theory, you could index them by their cardinal number, e.g.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I didn't not know that, again thanks a lot, I'm experiencing a revelation right now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well-known that

> If $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over the same field $K$ such that $V$ has a base $\{v_i; i \in I\}$ and $W$ has a base $\{w_j: j \in J\}$ such that $|I| = |J|$ then $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic as vector spaces.

The proof is quite easy: let $f: I \to J$ be a bijection, promised by $|I| = |J|$, then define $I(v_i) = w_{f(j)}$ and extend by linearity. Then $I: V \to W$ is an isomorphism.

If $I$ is an infinite set and $E$ has a base $\{b_i : i \in I\}$, then it is easy to see that $\{(b_i,0), (0, b_i): i \in I\}$ is a base for $E \oplus E$ (as an external direct sum; an internal sum makes no sense here) and its size is $|I| + |I| = |I|$ as $I$ is infinite. So $E$ and $E \oplus E$ have the same size basis,so 
are isomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

Your map is $x\mapsto (x,x)$. This is injective, but not surjective.

Let your basis be $e_1,e_2,e_3,\ldots$. Consider the subspace
spanned by $e_1,e_3,e_5,\ldots$ and the subspace spanned by $e_2,e_4,e_6,\ldots$.

Countability isn't crucial here, at least if you believe the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: Could you collaborate about your last sentence, please ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas He probbaly means that AC implies that for an infinite set $I$ we always have $|I| + |I|= |I|$, just as for countable.

Comment: @onurcanbektas For internal direct sums we use there are disjoint  subsets $I_1, I_2$ of $I$ with $I_1 \cup I_2 = I$ and $|I_1| = |I_2| = |I|$. This also follows from AC.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  $|I_1| = |I_2| = |I|$ is valid for only infinite case, right ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas of course, that's why we need AC in the first place.

Comment: I don't know AC, I haven't taken a main set theory course yet, I have just freshman year set theory knowledge, but I am really confused and not able to see how both of your arguments make the countability unnecessary in the view of AC, and I have no idea why do we need countability if one doesn't assumes AC to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the definition of direct sum $\oplus$ is slightly different than that:

If $A$ and $B$ are vector spaces with corresponding bases $\{a_1,\ldots, a_k\}$ and $\{b_1,\ldots, b_\ell\}$, then the direct sum $A\oplus B$ can be defined as the vector space whose basis is the *disjoint union* of the two bases:

$A\oplus B$ is a vector space with basis $\{a_1, \ldots, a_k, b_1, \ldots, b_\ell\}$.

If $A=B=E$, and $E$ has a countable basis $\{e_k : k\in \mathbb{N}\}$, then $E\oplus E$ also has a countable basis, because it is the disjoint union of two countably infinite sets.

To define a linear map between any two spaces $A\rightarrow B$, it is enough to define what it does to basis vectors. In the case of a linear isomorphism, the mapping must be a bijection between the basis vectors.

In particular, if you are sending $\phi: E \rightarrow E\oplus E$, how will you establish a bijection between the basis of $E$ and the basis of $E\oplus E$?

Call the basis of $E$ $\{e_i\}$ and refer to the basis of $E\oplus E$  as $\{\color{maroon}{e_i}\}\cup \{\color{green}{e_i}\}$. Here, the colors are used to indicate the direct sum.

Your proposed map is something like $\phi : e_i \mapsto \color{maroon}{e_i} + \color{green}{e_i}$. This does not span the whole space, because for example there is no vector $v$ such that $\phi(v) = \color{green}{e_i}$ only. (The proof of this comes from the fact that the $e_i$ are linearly independent, so there is no way to make a linear sum of them vanish without all of the coefficients being equal to zero.)

Instead, consider the following map on basis elements:

$$\phi(e_k) = \begin{cases}\color{maroon}{e_{k/2}}& \text{ if }k \text{ is even}\\\color{green}{e_{(k+1)/2}}& \text{ if }k \text{ is odd}\\\end{cases}$$

In other words,

$$\begin{align*}
e_1 & \mapsto \color{green}{e_1}\\
e_2 & \mapsto \color{maroon}{e_1}\\
e_3 & \mapsto \color{green}{e_2}\\
e_4 & \mapsto \color{maroon}{e_2}\\
e_5 & \mapsto \color{green}{e_3}\\
e_6 & \mapsto \color{maroon}{e_3}\\
\vdots & \\
\end{align*}$$

Then $\phi$ is a bijection between the basis of $E$ and the basis of $E\oplus E$, which means that it defines a linear isomorphism between them.

Comment: Thank your for your answer, but I have already know those (except that definition of the direct sum), and in my proof, I first mapped the basis to a subset of the codomain, and tried to show that the image of the basis a basis for the codomain.

Comment: If $E$ has the dimension 6, you image only contains the half of the basis, so how can this be a bijection ?

Comment: For a finite direct sum, like $V \oplus W$, this is just the product $V \times W$ in the ccordinatewise addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: @onurcanbektas It's the same idea as mine, and works only for infinite sets.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma But in the finite case, $E \times E$ has the dimension 2n when $E$ has the dimension n.

Comment: @onurcanbektas But you asked for the countably infinite case.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma No, actually I have asked only for countable case. I mean I don't see anywhere in the question saying that $E$ is infinite.

Comment: @onurcanbektas It's clear the author means "countable" = countably infinite, not finite. That would be expressed as "at most countable" = finite or countably infinite. It's quite common usage.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma One of the main reason why I like mathematics is its exactness, and I hate every time  I see such an idiotic usage of the words. I mean if we are not going to use the words as they are defined, then what is the point in defining them in that way ?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks  a lot by way.

Comment: @onurcanbektas it *is* exact if he specifies his terms somewhere earlier in the book, or refers for terminology for some standard text or paper. I don't know the book you're working from, so it might actually be clearer than you state. Like I said, it's quite standard not to include finite sets in "countable".

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Even the author were stated the usage of "countable" in the text, since I may not read the whole book, it is likely that I will not see his statements, unless he puts them in a list.